# Trouble getting a list of categories that have entries for a specific category group

Tags: categories

I have a long list of categories in a specific category group, but only want to show a list of the categories from this group that currently have an entry associated with them.

I've been trying to implement the solution that I found at this thread: [How can I output a list of categories that are not empty?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6762/how-can-i-output-a-list-of-categories-that-are-not-empty)

Only categories with related entries are showing. However, it's not being narrowed down to specific to a specific category group. Here's my code below:

```
{% set handshapeCategories = craft.categories.group('handshape').limit(null) %}
{% set entriesWithHandshapeCategories = craft.entries.relatedTo( handshapeCategories ).limit(null) %}
{% set handshapeCategoriesInUse = craft.categories.relatedTo(entriesWithHandshapeCategories) %}

{% for handshapeCategory in handshapeCategoriesInUse %}
    <h3>{{ handshapeCategory }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Any ideas why the shown categories are not being limited to categories from the 'handshape' category group?

Comment: If you got a solution to your problem, please consider accepting one of the answers below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would reverse your logic:

1. get all entries in whatever channel
2. display only categories (from a certain group) that have entries fetched in step 1 attached to them

Something along the lines of:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('myChannel').limit(null) %}
{% set activeCategories = craft.categories.group('myCatgroup').relatedTo(entries).find() %}
```

You can then use a simple `for` loop to display only the active categories

Comment: Yeah, this works really well and is easy to understand.

Comment: Glad it helps. You might also be interested in a more advanced set of tricks I blogged about: http://webstoemp.com/blog/manipulating-craft-elementcriteriamodel-with-twig/

Answer (score 1):

In order to limit the related categories to a specific category group I needed to add `.group('desiredCategoryGroup')` to the last line.

Here's an example of what I came up with:

```
{% set newsCategories = craft.categories.group('news').limit(null) %}
{% set soriesWithNewsCategory = craft.entries.relatedTo( newsCategories ).limit(null) %}
{% set newsCategoriesInUse = craft.categories.relatedTo(soriesWithNewsCategory).group('news') %}

<h2>List of News Categories in Use:</h2>
<ul>
    {% for category in newsCategoriesInUse %}
        <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it compares efficiency-wise, but another approach to this (which I personally find much easier to read) would be something like:

```
<ul>
  {% for handshapeCategory in craft.categories.group('handshape') %}
    {% if craft.entries.relatedTo(handShapeCategory).limit(1).getOne() is not empty %}
      <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In other words, for each category in the group, if we can fetch an entry for that category, display the title.

Comment: This is not very effective as it will result in one db query for each category.